# Immutable.js Map with numeric key (performance test included)

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm using Immutable.js with Redux in my React Native app.

Metadata, such as lookup tables, are fetched from a server and persisted locally in the app as Immutable.Map. The keys for the lookup values are integers (the primary key in the db).

When I fetch the data all integer keys are coerced into strings. This is normal behaviour for js objects. Thus, when a lookup Map is created, the keys will be strings.

Example:

```
let colors = Immutable.Map({
  '10': 'yellow',
  '20': 'pink',
  ..
})
```

The objects that are referencing the lookup values has the reference stored as numeric like this:

```
let michael = Immutable.Map({
  name: 'Michael',
  colorId: 10
})
```

Since Immutable.js does not coerce numeric keys to string I cannot do this:

```
let color = colors.get(michael.get('colorId'))
```

The above is the same as:

```
let color = colors.get(10)
```

This won't work, because the id is a string. This would work:

```
let color = colors.get('10')
```

I usually use Immutable.List to store datasets fetched from the server. To get an item I use find(). But the small lookup tables (essentially app metadata) are accessed very often and need to be speedy.

How do you solve this? Here are some alternatives to consider:

#### 1. Manually convert keys to strings when searching

```
let color = colors.get(michael.get('colorId') + '')
```

cons:

- Not an attractive solution. Seems error prune to me.

#### 2. Use plain js objects for lookup lists

pros:

- Object key lookup are fast in js
- Automatic coercion of keys to strings, both ways (writing and reading)

cons:

- Ideally I'd like to use Immutable.js everywhere.

#### 3. Use List.find() for lookup tables

pros:

- Same concept as for the big datasets

cons:

- I don't know the performance impact of using List.find() instead of Map.get()

#### 4. Carefully craft the Immutable.Map to use numeric key

```
let colors = new Immutable.Map()
  .set(10, 'yellow')
  .set(20, 'pink')
```

pros:

- Keys in the maps will match the value referencing the key (i.e. both are numeric)

cons:

- cumbersome
- Keys are already coerced to strings in the json object sent over the wire, so I'd essentially be converting them back to numeric (I think)

---

### Edit.. did some performance tests

Interesting data from a simple performance test.

- Lookup list of 10 items
- Find a value one million times
- Mac mini core i7 2.6

Immutable.Map with numeric keys: **185 ms**

Immutable.List using find(): **972 ms**

Plain JS object with coerced keys: **8 ms**

Plain JS array using find(): **127 ms**

As I'm using React Native I always have to look out for the 16 ms limit if I want to achieve 60 fps. The benchmark values does not seem to be linear. Running the test with only 100 lookups takes 1 ms with Map and 2 ms with List. That's quite expensive.

Have I done something wrong in the benchmarks? Otherwise I guess I'll have to leave Immutable.js out of this for now :(

#### Test code

```
let Immutable = require('immutable');

let mapTest = Immutable.Map()
  .set(1, Immutable.Map({value: 'one'}))
  .set(2, Immutable.Map({value: 'two'}))
  .set(3, Immutable.Map({value: 'three'}))
  .set(4, Immutable.Map({value: 'four'}))
  .set(5, Immutable.Map({value: 'five'}))
  .set(6, Immutable.Map({value: 'six'}))
  .set(7, Immutable.Map({value: 'seven'}))
  .set(8, Immutable.Map({value: 'eight'}))
  .set(9, Immutable.Map({value: 'nine'}))
  .set(10, Immutable.Map({value: 'ten'}));

let listTest = Immutable.fromJS([
  {key: 1,  value: 'one'},
  {key: 2,  value: 'two'},
  {key: 3,  value: 'three'},
  {key: 4,  value: 'four'},
  {key: 5,  value: 'five'},
  {key: 6,  value: 'six'},
  {key: 7,  value: 'seven'},
  {key: 8,  value: 'eight'},
  {key: 9,  value: 'nine'},
  {key: 10, value: 'ten'}
])

let objTest = {
  1:  {value: 'one'},
  2:  {value: 'two'},
  3:  {value: 'three'},
  4:  {value: 'four'},
  5:  {value: 'five'},
  6:  {value: 'six'},
  7:  {value: 'seven'},
  8:  {value: 'eight'},
  9:  {value: 'nine'},
  10: {value: 'ten'}
};

let arrayTest = [
  {key: 1,  value: 'one'},
  {key: 2,  value: 'two'},
  {key: 3,  value: 'three'},
  {key: 4,  value: 'four'},
  {key: 5,  value: 'five'},
  {key: 6,  value: 'six'},
  {key: 7,  value: 'seven'},
  {key: 8,  value: 'eight'},
  {key: 9,  value: 'nine'},
  {key: 10, value: 'ten'}
];

const runs = 1e6;
let i;
let key;
let hrStart;

console.log(' ')
console.log('mapTest -----------------------------')
key = 1;
hrstart = process.hrtime();
for(i=0; i<runs; i++) {
  let result = mapTest.getIn([key, 'value'] )
  key = (key >= 10) ? 1 : key + 1;
}
hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
console.info("Execution time (hr): %dms", hrend[0] * 1000 + hrend[1]/1000000);


console.log(' ')
console.log('listTest -----------------------------')
key = 1;
hrstart = process.hrtime();
for(i=0; i<runs; i++) {
  let result = listTest
    .find(item => item.get('key') === key)
    .get('value');
  key = (key >= 10) ? 1 : key + 1;
}
hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
console.info("Execution time (hr): %dms", hrend[0] * 1000 + hrend[1]/1000000);

console.log(' ')
console.log('arrayTest -----------------------------')
key = 1;
hrstart = process.hrtime();
for(i=0; i<runs; i++) {
  let result = arrayTest
    .find(item => item.key === key)
    .value

  key = (key >= 10) ? 1 : key + 1;
}
hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
console.info("Execution time (hr): %dms", hrend[0] * 1000 + hrend[1]/1000000);


console.log(' ')
console.log('objTest -----------------------------')
key = 1;
hrstart = process.hrtime();
for(i=0; i<runs; i++) {
  let result = objTest[key].value
  key = (key >= 10) ? 1 : key + 1;
}
hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
console.info("Execution time (hr): %dms", hrend[0] * 1000 + hrend[1]/1000000);
```

Comment: *'When I fetch the data all integer keys are coerced into strings. This is normal behaviour for js objects."* - why?

Comment: I don't know the thoughts behind this. But that's the way it is. {1: 'one'} will be coerced to {'1': 'one}.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this?

Comment: Solution for what? The coercion is what it is. It’s a JS thing. But I usually create Immutable.map via the array syntax to keep the integer key, like this: const myMap = Immutable.Map([[key, value], [key, value]]). If key is an integer it will be kept that way.