# Performance: Immutable.js Map vs List vs plain JS

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

**Question**

Is there something wrong with my benchmark? How can Immutable.js find() be 8 times slower than array.find()?

Ok, not entirely fair, since I'm using Immutable.Map inside of the Immutable.List. But to me this is a real world example. If I use Immutable.js it's to protect immutability and to gain performance in some aspects (where structural sharing come to play). The would be no point in using Immutable.js only at the root of the object.

The below benchmark is actually from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999419/immutable-js-map-with-numeric-key-performance-test-included) (mine as well). I was so surprised by the results, I had to post it separately to get it straight. Have I done something wrong in my benchmarks, or is the performance difference really this big?

**Background**

Some of the data in my app could be considered app metadata. The original data lives in a database at the server. Updates to the metadata will not be done often. The app will check for updated metadata on startup.

I'm using Immutable.js everywhere, but I will go back to plain js for the metadata. There is no need for fancy structural sharing for this kind of data.

**The test is to find values by key in a collection**

- Collection of 10 items
- Find a value one million times
- Mac mini core i7 2.6

**Result:**

- Plain JS object with coerced keys: **8 ms**
- Plain JS array using find(): **127 ms**
- Immutable.Map with numeric keys: **185 ms**
- Immutable.List using find(): **972 ms** !! *I'm baffled*

As I'm using React Native I always have to look out for the 16 ms limit if I want to achieve 60 fps. The benchmark values does not seem to be linear. Running the test with only 100 lookups takes 1 ms with Map and 2 ms with List. That's quite expensive.

#### Test code

```
let Immutable = require('immutable');

let mapTest = Immutable.Map()
  .set(1, Immutable.Map({value: 'one'}))
  .set(2, Immutable.Map({value: 'two'}))
  .set(3, Immutable.Map({value: 'three'}))
  .set(4, Immutable.Map({value: 'four'}))
  .set(5, Immutable.Map({value: 'five'}))
  .set(6, Immutable.Map({value: 'six'}))
  .set(7, Immutable.Map({value: 'seven'}))
  .set(8, Immutable.Map({value: 'eight'}))
  .set(9, Immutable.Map({value: 'nine'}))
  .set(10, Immutable.Map({value: 'ten'}));

let listTest = Immutable.fromJS([
  {key: 1,  value: 'one'},
  {key: 2,  value: 'two'},
  {key: 3,  value: 'three'},
  {key: 4,  value: 'four'},
  {key: 5,  value: 'five'},
  {key: 6,  value: 'six'},
  {key: 7,  value: 'seven'},
  {key: 8,  value: 'eight'},
  {key: 9,  value: 'nine'},
  {key: 10, value: 'ten'}
])

let objTest = {
  1:  {value: 'one'},
  2:  {value: 'two'},
  3:  {value: 'three'},
  4:  {value: 'four'},
  5:  {value: 'five'},
  6:  {value: 'six'},
  7:  {value: 'seven'},
  8:  {value: 'eight'},
  9:  {value: 'nine'},
  10: {value: 'ten'}
};

let arrayTest = [
  {key: 1,  value: 'one'},
  {key: 2,  value: 'two'},
  {key: 3,  value: 'three'},
  {key: 4,  value: 'four'},
  {key: 5,  value: 'five'},
  {key: 6,  value: 'six'},
  {key: 7,  value: 'seven'},
  {key: 8,  value: 'eight'},
  {key: 9,  value: 'nine'},
  {key: 10, value: 'ten'}
];

const runs = 1e6;
let i;
let key;
let hrStart;

console.log(' ')
console.log('mapTest -----------------------------')
key = 1;
hrstart = process.hrtime();
for(i=0; i<runs; i++) {
  let result = mapTest.getIn([key, 'value'] )
  key = (key >= 10) ? 1 : key + 1;
}
hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
console.info("Execution time (hr): %dms", hrend[0] * 1000 + hrend[1]/1000000);


console.log(' ')
console.log('listTest -----------------------------')
key = 1;
hrstart = process.hrtime();
for(i=0; i<runs; i++) {
  let result = listTest
    .find(item => item.get('key') === key)
    .get('value');
  key = (key >= 10) ? 1 : key + 1;
}
hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
console.info("Execution time (hr): %dms", hrend[0] * 1000 + hrend[1]/1000000);

console.log(' ')
console.log('arrayTest -----------------------------')
key = 1;
hrstart = process.hrtime();
for(i=0; i<runs; i++) {
  let result = arrayTest
    .find(item => item.key === key)
    .value

  key = (key >= 10) ? 1 : key + 1;
}
hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
console.info("Execution time (hr): %dms", hrend[0] * 1000 + hrend[1]/1000000);


console.log(' ')
console.log('objTest -----------------------------')
key = 1;
hrstart = process.hrtime();
for(i=0; i<runs; i++) {
  let result = objTest[key].value
  key = (key >= 10) ? 1 : key + 1;
}
hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);
console.info("Execution time (hr): %dms", hrend[0] * 1000 + hrend[1]/1000000);
```

Comment: What is the question? Lookups using `.find()` are of course going to be slower than lookups by key.

Comment: Sorry. I have now emphasised the question.

Comment: _"Have I done something wrong in my benchmarks, or is the performance difference really this big?"_ What is `process`?

Comment: You are convoluting the question by adding a map in there, it makes no sense to compare a lookup on a map with one on an array

Comment: To me it makes sense. If I am to use Immutable.js there is no point in using it half way. That's why my examples are built around real world usage alternatives (to me anyway).

Comment: @Michael nobody would question why a lookup on a map is faster, just saying. Now, if you were talking about why sometimes a map lookup can be slower, that would be something worth talking about. Also, now your question is not about a single issue, making it harder for a single answer to be accepted, one person may give you a great reason why the immutable list is slower and someone may give you another great reason why a map is faster, which one do  you mark as accepted? That's why you should ask the simplest question possible.

Comment: In the case of Immutable.js I haven't found any docs to help me select between Map and List. Now I'm inclined to store all of my datasets as Map using the original primary key as key. This would give me 5 times faster key lookups. Are there any cons?

Comment: The whole point of using a map in any programming language is to have fast lookups by key.

Comment: Yes, but still Immutable.map is 8 times slower than the plain js object, which is also a map.

Comment: @Michael Is your question, "Wy is ImmutableJS slower than its JavaScript counterparts for array and maps?" If so, isn't it expected that an abstraction  using JavaScript will be slower than the language itself?

Comment: Yes, it is. But with all the buzz around Immutable.js, and people saying the performance diff is negligable, I think 800% is a tad to high. Oh well.. I posted my Q because I wish I had found a similar post before diving into Immutable. Of course I should have benchmarked it before.. And I probably shouldn't have posted this on SE as it is more of a discussion than a single question.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. Abstractions are almost always going to beess performant than lower level operations.

Comment: @Mardoxx https://jsperf.com/object-freeze-vs-immutable/11 . I know you will notice it but to make sure immutableJS is not the only abstraction in that  test

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The short answer is that the representation of data structures used by Immutable.js requires a lot of additional overhead to iterate through the elements of a List, compared to a native JS array.

### Benchmarking Immutable.List.find and Array.find

Your benchmark is good, but we can simplify matters a bit by getting rid of the nested map; you're right to consider performance for realistic problems, but it can be helpful in understanding performance differences to simplify the problem as much as possible. It's also often useful in benchmarking to consider how performance changes over different input sizes. For instance, it's possible that in Immutable.js, `List.prototype.find` is implemented in such a way that the intitial call and setup take awhile but that the subsequent iterating through the List performs similarly to native JS Arrays; in this case, the difference in performance between native JS Arrays and Immutable.js lists would decrease for long input lengths (this turns out not to be the case).

Let's also create our own find function for native JS arrays, `Array.prototype.ourFind` to compare to the native `Array.prototype.find` to determine if the difference could in part be due to the performance of JS functions themselves vs. performance of functions built-in to the implementation.

```js
Array.prototype.ourFind = function(predicate) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (predicate(this[i])) return this[i];
  }
}

function arrayRange(len) {
  return new Array(len).fill(null).map((_, i) => i);
}

function immutListRange(len) {
  return Immutable.fromJS(arrayRange(len));
}

function timeFind(coll, find, iters) {
  let startTime = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    let searchVal = i % coll.length,
      result = find.call(coll, item => item === searchVal);
  }
  return Math.floor(performance.now() - startTime);
}

const MIN_LEN = 10,
  MAX_LEN = 1e4,
  ITERS = 1e5;

console.log('\t\tArray.find\tArray.ourFind\tList.find');
for (let len = MIN_LEN; len <= MAX_LEN; len *= 10) {
  console.log(`${len}\t\t\t` +
    `${timeFind(arrayRange(len), Array.prototype.find, ITERS)}\t\t\t` +
    `${timeFind(arrayRange(len), Array.prototype.ourFind, ITERS)}\t\t\t` +
    `${timeFind(immutListRange(len), Immutable.List.prototype.find, ITERS)}`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

In Chrome, I get:

```
Length .    Array.find  Array.ourFind   List.find
10          28          13              96
100         60          44              342
1000        549         342             3016
10000       5533        3142            36423
```

I got roughly similar results in Firefox and Safari. A few points to note:

1. The difference between `List.find` vs. `Array.find` is not simply due to native (i.e. interpreter built-in) implementations vs. JS implementations, because a JS implementation of `Array.ourFind` performs at least as well as `Array.find`.
2. All implementations work in O(n) time (i.e. execution time is linear with respect to input length). This is to be expected, since a find algorithm will always have to work by iterating through the collection elements until it finds one for which the predicate returns true.
3. `Immutable.List.find` is ~6-fold slower than `Array.find`, consistent with your benchmarking results.

### Immutable.List data representation

To understand why `Immutable.List.find` is so much slower, you first have to consider how `Immutable.List` represents the list contents.

A quick way to do this is to generate an `Immutable.List` and examine it in the console:

```
console.log(immutListRange(1000));  // immutListRange defined above
```

[image]

So essentially it looks like `Immutable.List` represents the contents as a tree with a branching factor of 32.

Now consider what it will take to run a find operation on data that are represented in this way. You will have to start at the root node, and traverse the tree down to the first leaf node (which contains an Array with the actual data), and iterate through the contents of the leaf; if the element is not found, you have to go to the next leaf node and search that Array, and so on. It's a more complex operation than merely searching through a single array, and it requires overhead to execute.

### Watching Immutable.List.find at work

A great way to appreciate the work that `Immutable.List.find` does is to set a break point in your debugger of choice and step through the operation. You'll see that `Immutable.List.Find` is not nearly as simple an operation as merely looping through a single Array.

### Additional comments

The tree representation of data in Immutable.js presumably accelerates other operations, but entails a performance penalty with some functions, such as find.

As a side note, I don't think in most cases that the choice to use immutable data structures is driven by performance considerations. There may be some cases where immutable data structures perform better than mutable ones (and certainly immutable data structures make parallel computing less complex, which enables significant performance gain), but there will be many cases when the opposite is true. Rather, the choice of immutability is, in most cases, driven by design considerations--i.e. using immutable data structures forces program designs that will be more robust and, in the long run, increase developer productivity.

Comment: You just rocked my world. Man, that was soooo good! Loved the explanation.

Answer (score 13):

JS engines are very good at optimising 'hot' operations - ones that get repeated a lot and that are as simple as possible (for instance [TurboFan in V8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1FBosB5tjM)). Plain JS objects and array functions are *always* going to beat a library like Immutable.js, where [`List`](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/List.js) calls [`Collection`](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/Collection.js) calls [`Seq`](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/Seq.js) calls [`Operations`](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/master/src/Operations.js) (and so on), especially when the actions are repeated many times.

Immutable.js appears to be designed for convenience of use and avoiding a lot of the nastyness of mutable JS collections, rather than pure performance.

If you have a million things, use a low level JS object or array (or Web Assembly, if performance is critical). If you have a thousand things and *need* to be certain of not dropping a frame then plain JS is still the way to go. These are specialised cases though - for most use cases the convenience of Immutable.js is worth the speed reduction.

Comment: `JS engines are very good at optimising 'hot' operations - ones that get repeated a lot and that are as simple as possible.` - do they? This sounds largely apocryphal... Sounds to me that it is rather the case that simple things translate to simpler operations which can more easily map to best choice pre defined algorithms. This isn't optimisation of code, this is common sense.

Comment: @Mardoxx For instance [V8 does _adaptive optimization_](https://v8project.blogspot.co.uk/2017/05/launching-ignition-and-turbofan.html). [IonMonkey](https://wiki.mozilla.org/IonMonkey) does something similar.

Comment: @Mardoxx - as JS types can change on the fly the interpreter can't always make assumptions on the first _pass_ - in `a + b` what type are `a` and `b`? However, if the same execution repeats with the same types (say both `a` and `b` are always `number`) then it can create an optimised version just for number types. That is then _slower_ if strings come along later, but if it repeats again with numbers its _much_ quicker.

Comment: @Mardoxx here is a [better description on TurboFan in V8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1FBosB5tjM)

Answer (score 3):

The benchmark does not consider all the data types that Immutable has to offer. Immutable actually has some features, that plain objects/arrays do not: [OrderedSet](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedSet) and [OrderedMap](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedMap) have the benefits of both indexed arrays/List and key-based structures like object/Map.

Below is an adapted version of the nicely done test of @Keith, which shows that we can actually become faster than Array.find, especially with large data sets.

Of course, this comes at some cost too:

- Set/Map does not allow duplicates (not different to object though).
- Behind the scenes, the ordered variants combine a Map/Set with a list, so it consume more memory.

> Note that OrderedSet are more expensive than non-ordered Set and may consume more memory. OrderedSet#add is amortized O(log32 N), but not stable.

```js
function arrayFind(coll, searchVal) {
  return coll.find(item => item === searchVal);
}

function immutableSetGet(coll, searchVal) {
  return coll.get(searchVal);
}

function arrayRange(len) {
  return new Array(len).fill(null).map((_, i) => i);
}

function immutOrderedSetRange(len) {
  return Immutable.OrderedSet(arrayRange(len));
}

function timeFind(what, coll, find, iters) {
  let startTime = performance.now();
  let size = coll.length || coll.size;
  for (let i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    let searchVal = i % size,
      result = find(coll, searchVal);
  }
  return Math.floor(performance.now() - startTime);
}

const MIN_LEN = 100,
  MAX_LEN = 1e5,
  ITERS = 50000;

console.log('\t\t\tArray.find\tOrderedSet.find');
for (let len = MIN_LEN; len <= MAX_LEN; len *= 10) {
  console.log(`${len}\t\t\t` +
    `${timeFind('find', arrayRange(len), arrayFind, ITERS)}\t\t` +
    `${timeFind('set', immutOrderedSetRange(len), immutableSetGet, ITERS)}`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.js"></script>
```

Example results, in Chrome 86:

```
        Array.find   OrderedSet.find
100        10             18
1000       10              6
10000      74             10
100000    346             11
```